# Unable to find docker image locally

Tags: macos, docker, docker-run

I was following [this post](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/lets-talk-about-docker-artifacts-27454560384f) - the reference code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/shakyShane/cra-docker). I have cloned the repository on my local.

The project has got a react app inside it. I'm trying to run it on my local following **step 7** on the [same post](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/lets-talk-about-docker-artifacts-27454560384f):

```
docker run -p 8080:80 shakyshane/cra-docker
```

This returns:

```
Unable to find image 'shakyshane/cra-docker:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for shakyshane/cra-docker, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried login to docker again but looks like since it belongs to [@shakyShane](https://medium.com/@shakyShane) I cannot access it.

I idiotically tried `npm start` too but it's not a simple react app running on node - it's in the container and containers are not controlled by `npm`

Looks like `docker pull shakyshane/cra-docker:latest` throws this:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for shakyshane/cra-docker, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

So the question is how do I run this docker image on my local mac machine?

Comment: First pull the docker image using the command "docker pull shakyshane/cra-docker:latest"

Comment: @rajashekar I will try it now. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact build command you used in step 6?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I cloned the whole repository. The step 6 is the [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0bd28c5a53a61d8850433f62f6cf85de#file-dockerfile)

Comment: Step 6 instructs you to run `docker build . -t shakyshane/cra-docker`. That builds the image with the name `shakyshane/cra-docker` which you are trying to use in step 7. Since it cannot be found, it would seem the image was not built, at least not with the same name.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Damn you, man! Holy moly! I used `docker build . -t xameeramir/cra-docker` I think this is where I am a culprit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I find myself in this situation when the image exists, but the docker run command comes from a shell script that is executed on the terminal from the same dir as the command itself. So when running the command manually, it runs. When running the same command from a shell script at the same directory level, it fails... If you read this and have the same problem, maybe raise a new question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Well this is illogical but still sharing so future people like me don't get stuck.

The problem was that I was trying to run a docker image which [doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512769/how-to-run-somone-elses-docker-image-on-local-machine#comment99612033_56512769).

I needed to build the image:

```
docker build . -t xameeramir/cra-docker
```

And then run it:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 xameeramir/cra-docker
```

Answer (score 41):

In my case, my image had TAG specified with it and I was not using it.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
testimage          testtag            189b7354c60a        13 hours ago        88.3MB
```

`Unable to find image 'testimage:latest' locally` for this command `docker run testimage`

So specifying tag like this - `docker run testimage:testtag` worked for me

Comment: Hi (docker newb here), excuse my ignorance please. How did you print that top line of your comment, with the repo details??

Comment: It's ``docker image list``

Answer (score 38):

Posting my solution since non of the above worked.
Working on macbook M1 pro.

The issue I had is that the image was built as arm/64. And I was running the command:

```
docker run --platform=linux/amd64 ...
```

So I had to build the image for amd/64 platform in order to run it.

Command below:

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 ...
```

In conclusion your docker image platform and docker run platform needs to be the same from what I experienced.

Comment: that was exactly my issue, the error is image not found if the image is the wrong architecture. thanks for your answer!

Comment: I had a similar problem when switching to M1... `docker build --platform=amd64 -t foo .` and then `docker run --platform=amd64 foo` would complain it couldn't find the image.  If I remove the platform flag on docker run then it finds it but warns.  Instead the right fix was using the full platform `linux/amd64` on the run command.  I added it to the build command too for symmetry.

Comment: I just tried! `docker run --platform=linux/amd64 [CONTAINER_ID]`, but not work (unable to find image), what did i go wrong?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the docker image did exist on the system and still I couldn't run the container locally, so I used the exact image ID instead of image name and tag, like this:

```
docker run myContainer c29150c8588e
```

Answer (score 8):

I received this error message when I **typed the name/character wrong**.  That is, "name1\name2" instead of "name1/name2" (wrong slash).

Comment: You are a good man bro, it worked for me too :))), the issue is the path of linux vs windows which in this case it is windows based path and it worked ::)))

Answer (score 3):

This just happened to me because my local docker vm on macos ran out of disk space.

I just deleted some old images using `docker image prune` and it started working correctly again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I saw this error when I had logged in to the dockerhub in my docker desktop. The repo I was pulling was local to my enterprise. Once i logged out of dockerhub, the pull worked.

Answer (score 1):

shakyshane/cra-docker Does not exist in that user's repo https://hub.docker.com/u/shakyshane/

Comment: Agree @RichardBarber it was a mistake of mine. Thanks anyways for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to run an imagen that does not exists. If you are executing a Dockerfile, the image was not created until Dockerfile pass with no errors; so when Dockerfile tries to run the image, it can't find it. Be sure you have no errors in the execution of your scripts.

Comment: Hey, I think this is not the right answer. The docker image is not public and so this user cannot download the image.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer can be the correct one!.. make sure you have permissions to execute the command, use:

`sudo docker run -p 8080:80 shakyshane/cra-docker`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't realise there was a difference between `docker run` and `docker start`, and I kept using the run command when I should've been using the start command.

FYI, `run` is for building and creating the docker container, `start` is to just start a stopped container

Answer (score 0):

Use -d

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8000:8000 rasa/duckling
```

learn about -d here

```
sudo docker run --help
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, i build image on mac-m1-pro with this command `docker build -t hello_k8s_world:0.0.1 .`, when is run this image the issue appear.

After read [Master Yi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71269729/19630216)'s answer, i realize the crux of the matter and rebuild my images like this `docker build --platform=arm64 -t hello_k8s_world:0.0.1 .`

Finally，it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since Docker 23.0, `docker build` has become an alias for `docker buildx build`.

You might be using a custom builder instance.

Set the builder instance to default with this command and run your build command again.

```bash
docker buildx use default
```