# Accessing the files out of docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have created a docker container image, and working inside the container (setting up filesystem, creating code files, installing dependencies etc).

On my Ubuntu machine, I keep a huge file under a directory so called `/dataset/my_data/`.

When I work in the container, it is not straightforward to access the above directory. Is there any possibility to access it from inside the container image interactively? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the directory as a volume:

```
docker ... --mount type=bind,source=/dataset/my_data,target=/some/directory
```

For example, to run a container called `my-container` with a bound volume:

```
docker run -it --mount \
  type=bind,source=/dataset/my_data,target=/target/directory \
  my-container
```

For all available possibilities, see [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am very new and a bit dummy in usage of docker. Let's say my container ID is 12345, and the directory where I want to mount is /root. What would be the comment to do it? I was reading the tutorial you have showed me, even before asking this question. But I couldn't understand anything. That's why I asked this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does the more complete example help you?

Comment: Sami, thanks for your edit. However, the example what you give does not help with binding the folder into the existing container what I already have. I get this error: Unable to find image 'hasan:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hasan, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'. Given the fact that my container name is 'hasan'

Comment: That is a different problem that has been addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512769/unable-to-find-docker-image-locally

Comment: I already have the image, do not need to build it. I just have to bind the folder in my already created docker image. I don't want to create a new fresh image for binding.

Comment: no, it doesn't. However it shows up when I use docker ps -a.

Comment: In that case I fear you don't have to image locally, as the error message says. This is not related to the original question.